# fetch data from db and display in ddl using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following error on `CodeIgniter`.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message:  Undefined variable: assigned_to
>   Filename: admin/insert.php
>   Line Number: 20
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   Filename: admin/insert.php
>   Line Number: 20 "

In my controller page,

```
<?
$data['assigned_to'] = $this->user_model->get_ddl();
var_dump($data['assigned_to']);
?>
```

Model page:

```
public function get_ddl()
        {
                $this-> db ->select('user_name');
                $this-> db ->from('user');
                $query = $this->db->get();
                return $query->result_array(); 
        }
```

View page:

```
<tr><td>Assigned To </td><td><select name='ddl_uname'>
<? 
foreach($assigned_to as $row)
{
        echo '<option value="'.$row->user_name.'">'.$row->user_name.'</option>';
}?>
</select></td></tr>
```

Comment: where is this line in your code `admin/insert.php Line Number: 20`

Comment: also post your complete controller function code

Comment: that's line I mentioned on "view page" foreach () and $assigned_to.

Comment: check what result do you get from modal `get_ddl();`

Answer (score 0):

Just assign to your model result into a variable then pass it to your `data array`

**MODEL**

```
$assigned_to=$this->user_model->get_ddl();// assign to a variable then pass to data array
$data['assigned_to']=$assigned_to; 
var_dump($data['assigned_to']);

 $this->load->view('view_name', $data);
```